# Arithmetic mean of positive integers less than an integer $N$ and co-prime with $N$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $N>1$ be a positive integer. What will be the Arithmetic mean of positive integers less than $N$ and co-prime with $N$?

Getting no idea how to proceed!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(The way the problem reads at this time is "What will be the Arithmetic mean of positive integers less than $N$ and co-prime with $N$?" (I mention this in case there was some other version of the question and it got edited.))

$n$ is coprime to $N$ if and only if $N-n$ is coprime to $N$.

The average of $n$ and $N-n$ is $N/2$.

The average of the averages of all such cases is the average of a bunch of numbers each equal to $N/2$.

The average of all numbers in $\{1,\dots,N\}$ that are coprime to $N$ is therefore $N/2$.

**Later edit:** Here's an example.  The numbers in $\{1,\dots,20\}$ that are coprime to $20$ are $1,3,7,9,11,13,17,19$.

They come in these pairs:
\begin{align}
1, & 19 \text{ (The average of these two is $10$.)} \\
3, & 17 \text{ (The average of these two is $10$.)} \\
7, & 13 \text{ (The average of these two is $10$.)} \\
9, & 11 \text{ (The average of these two is $10$.)}
\end{align}
Now take the average of all those $10$s.  The average is $10$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

As $(a,n)=(n-a,n),$

Let $$S=\sum_{1\le a\le n,(a,n)=1}a,$$

then $$S=\sum_{1\le a\le n,(a,n)=1}(n-a)$$

$$\implies2S=\phi(n)(a+n-a)=n\phi(n)$$ where $\phi(n)$ is the Euler [Totient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) function, the number of positive integers $<n$ and co-prime to $n$

The Arithmetic mean will be $\frac S{\phi(n)}$

Comment: It looks to me as if you've made the problem far more complicated than it is and your answer is wrong.  The way the problem reads at this time is "What will be the Arithmetic mean of positive integers less than $N$ and co-prime with $N$?"  (I mention this in case you read some other version of the question and it got edited.)

Comment: @MichaelHardy, what is wrong here? I just changed the case of $N$ from upper to lower? Here the mean will be $\frac{n\phi(n)}{2\phi(n)}=\frac n2$

Comment: See my answer.  You've made it far more complicated than it is.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, but what is wrong here????

Comment: The sum of the totients of $1,\dots,9$ is $28$.  The totient of $10$ is $4$.  So $S/\varphi(n)=28/4=7$.  But the average of $1,3,7,9$ is $5$, not $7$.

Comment: It seems that you've misunderstood lab's answer - I advise you to read it again. However, this answer does indeed over-complicate things :)

Comment: OK, you say "The sum of the totients".  But apparently you really mean the sum of the numbers less than $n$ that are coprime to $n$, not the sum of their totients.  That would make your answer correct, but not useful, since you haven't found that sum.

Comment: Actually, read again. The arithmetic mean is $\frac{S}{\phi(n)},$ and he's correctly pointed out that $2S = n\phi(n).$

Comment: OK, it looks as if you're proposing to sum the _totients_ of numbers less than $n$ but coprime to $n$.  If $n=10$, that would give you $\varphi(1)+\varphi(3)+\varphi(7)+\varphi(9)$ $=1+2+6+4=13$.  Then you're dividing by $\varphi(10)=4$.  This gives you the average of four totients, $13/4=3.25$.  But what the question asked for was the average of $1,3,7,9$, which is $5$.

Comment: @lyj : No, that's the mean of the totients of the numbers less than $n$ and coprime to $n$.  That's not what the question asked for.  It asked simply for the mean of the numbers less than $n$ and coprime to $n$, not for the mean of the totients of those numbers.

Comment: That's not what he's done at all - he's summed the numbers relatively prime to $n$ and called that sum $S,$ though it's true that he writes "the sum of the totients" (which is not clear).

Comment: @lyj : He said "where $S$ is the sum of the totients".  Maybe he thought "totients" meant numbers less than $n$ and relatively prime to $n$.  I take "totient" to mean a value of the totient function.  If we were to construe "totient" the way he did, then his answer would be correct but not useful: If merely says the average is the sum of the terms divided by the number of terms, but it fails to say that the average is $n/2$.

Comment: I know that's what he says, but that's clearly not what is meant when he writes $2S = \phi(n)(a + n-a) = n\phi(n).$ This represents the sum of all numbers less than $n$ relatively prime to $n,$ of which there are $\phi(n).$

Comment: To be even more clear - he counts each pair $(a, n-a)$ twice. Once for $a,$ once for $(n-a).$ This gives the total count of $\phi(n).$ That's why he has $2S$ instead of just $S.$ Regardless, this discussion wouldn't have arisen had lab written his answer in a less confusing manner. I've already up-voted yours and just didn't want people to incorrectly assume this answer is incorrect.

Comment: The answer is correct ONLY if one construes "totient" as meaning a number less than $n$ and coprime to $n$.  However, let us not that the answer does not even make use of the fact that if $a$ is such a number then so is $n-a$.  One could instead just say "Let $S$ be the sum of the numbers less than $n$ and coprime to $n$.  Since $\varphi(n)$ is how many there are, their average is $S/\varphi(n)$." That argument in no way makes use of the fact that they come in pairs, even though that is mentioned here.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, I think the definition of totient is unambiguous.Are you aware any other definition?

Comment: @lyj, Please have a look into the edited answer if I could make it less abstruse.Btw, thanks for your input.

Comment: I understood it as it was before, but now I think it should be impossible to misinterpret it.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee : I am aware of only one definition in conventional use, and your posting seems to use two.  The totient of $10$ is $4$, because there are four numbers less than $10$ that are coprime to $10$.  Those four numbers are $1,3,7,9$.  But you seemed to be calling the numbers $1,3,7,9$ "totients", rather than saying the totient is $4$.

Comment: At any rate, this answer is unduly complicated and not useful.  You could say $S=\sum a$ where $a$ runs through the set of numbers less than $n$ that are coprime to $n$, and $\varphi(n)$ is how many such numbers there are, and therefore their average is $S/\varphi(n)$.  That much works without using two different methods of summing.  So all that stuff about two different ways of adding them up is just a complication that isn't getting used for anything.  And your bottom line only says the average is the sum divided by the number of terms, but fails to say that the average is $n/2$.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee : I had always thought the word "totient" was unambiguous, but now you have suggested there's another definition.  Therefore I have posted a question about it: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452259/definition-of-totient