# Definition of "totient"

Tags: terminology, arithmetic-functions

I had always taken the term "totient" to be defined by saying that the totient of a positive integer $n$ is the number of positive integers less than $n$ that are coprime to $n$.  Thus, for example, the totient of $10$ is $4$.

In a discussion under [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451983/arithmetic-mean-of-positive-integers-less-than-an-integer-n-and-co-prime-with), someone suggests, without being very explicit, that "the totients of $n$" are those positive integers less than $n$ and coprime to $n$.  By that definition, the totients of $10$ would be $1,3,7,9$.  (He has since edited his answer so that it no longer uses the word "totient".)

Am I the only one **not** aware of the second definition, or is the person who said that the only person who *was* aware of it?  Or might some other alternative be true?

Comment: I've never seen it used that way. I'd be willing to call that the "totient set."

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : To be clear, WHICH of the two ways have you never seen it used?

Comment: I have never seen it referred to in the second way it's not called the "Euler Cardinality of Totient Function" is it?

Comment: "totie(n)s" as often (as), corresponds to "quotie(n)s", how often. Make of that what you will, my Latin has come to an end (I don't understand why Euler called it thus).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I the only one not aware of the second definition[?]

Of course not.  Most people don't know any definition of "totient", including a positive proportion (it is not implausible that the proportion may exceed $\frac{1}{2}$) of mathematicians.

> [O]r is the person who said that the only person who was aware of it?

Among the billions of people in the world, is there *someone* else who uses "totient" to mean the set of reduced residues modulo $n$ (**or** an element of that set) rather than its cardinality?  It seems overwhelmingly probable, but I don't know of an explicit example.

I think these questions are not very fruitful.  Let's instead ask: is it *standard* to define the totient as the set of reduced residues modulo $n$ (**or** an element of that set)?  No, it is not.   I am a number theorist, and I have never encountered this alternative definition.

Let me reiterate though that the proportion of the mathematical community which does not know any definition for "totient" is large and growing.  In much contemporary writing the word simply isn't used: rather one says **Euler's $\varphi$ function**.  If you are going to use the word "totient" in any context, it would be safest to give the definition or at least drop the keywords "Euler" and "$\varphi$".

Comment: I hope your first four paragraphs were not intended to be taken too seriously.  At any rate, the person who used that strange definition---the second one in my question---did not define it as a set, but rather as a member of that set.  I.e. each number less than $n$ but coprime to $n$ was one of the "totients".

Comment: $@$Michael: I intend the second and fourth paragraphs to be taken as seriously -- neither more nor less -- as the first and third paragraphs.  About the proposed alternate definition: noted, thanks.  It does not change my answer much.